# New Objective-c Literals in 4.4

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, xcode4.4

I can write `@42`, which creates an `NSNumber` with `int` value 42. Can I do this with a variable, like `@someIntVar`? Obviously I tried it and it doesn't work (which sucks because then I have to go through `[NSNumber numberWithInt:someIntVar]`). Is it possible with a slightly different syntax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I strongly suggest you read the official clang documentation on the matter: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

But, to box a variable, or any expression, you can use parentheses:

```
 id num = @(someIntVar);
```

Comment: Just to add to that, you can also do that with C string variables to create `NSStrings` (same `@(...)` syntax)