# Accessing keys in NSDictionary using [key] notation?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, objective-c-literals

I have just realised that I can access `NSDictionary` using both `objectForKey:` and dict[key]?

```
NSDictionary *coordsDict = @{@"xpos": @5.0, @"ypos": @7.2, @"zpos": @15.7};
NSLog(@"XPOS: %@", coordsDict[@"xpos"]);
NSLog(@"XPOS: %@", [coordsDict objectForKey:@"xpos"]);
```

Can anyone tell me if this has been hiding from me all along or if its some fairly recent change to the language?

**EDIT:** The question does not generically refer to the new string literals, but more specifically to accessing NSDictionary with the same string literal syntax you would use for NSArray. I obviously overlooked this and just wanted to check when this particular syntax was added.

Comment: They are fairly new "Objective-C Literals", but have been much-discussed here.  Duplicate questions will follow. http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Comment: The question should rather be: how could you've been hiding from this broadly discussed language extension coming within the last year.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120153/new-objective-c-literals-in-4-4

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693647/is-there-some-literal-dictionary-or-array-syntax-in-objective-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the details of "Objective-C Literals" mentioned in the Xcode 4.4 release notes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347722/what-are-the-details-of-objective-c-literals-mentioned-in-the-xcode-4-4-releas)

Comment: Thank you, most of these seem to focus on the inclusion of object literals (i.e. @{} or @() and @[] for NSArray, very few bother to mention that @[] also works with NSDictionay which is why I believe I over looked it. Much appreciated ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a new addition to Xcode 4.4+ and relies on Apple's LLVM+Clang compiler. It's a new feature :) Arrays can also be accessed with the same notation: `myObjectArray[4]`.

If you're interested in adding this new feature to your own classes (called subscripting), there's a few methods you can implement:

```
@interface NSArray(Subscripting)
- (id)objectAtIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)index;
@end

@interface NSMutableArray(Subscripting)
- (void)setObject:(id)obj atIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)index;
@end

@interface NSDictionary(Subscripting)
- (id)objectForKeyedSubscript:(id)key;
@end

@interface NSMutableDictionary(Subscripting)
- (void)setObject:(id)obj forKeyedSubscript:(id <NSCopying>)key;
@end
```

If you implement any of these methods on your own classes, you can subscript on them. This is also how you can add this feature to OS X 10.7 too!

Comment: @fuzzygoat Go wild with this: I added a category on `NSSegmentedControl` to make segment addition FAR easier programmatically. Little things like this make my day a lot more fun! :)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to "Modern Objective-C", introduced in iOS 6.

See the WWDC 2012 video: [Migrating to Modern Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=405).

So, no, the feature is not really new and you have overlooked it... ;-)