# Extracting value from NSDictionary with brackets vs. objectForKey: or valueForKey:

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-literals

I was wondering what this convenience method stood for but was unable to find any answers for it.

What exactly does `theDictionary[@"key"]` do when wanting to extract a value from a dictionary? Is it using `valueForKey:` or `objectForKey:`?

What is better performance wise? Is it better to write the whole message like `[theDictionary objectForKey:@"key"]` or is the convenience method sufficient?

Comment: [Accessing keys in NSDictionary using key notation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14878468)

Answer (score 4):

Let's have that in a context:

There are different ways to access an object that is accessable by a key.

A. Key-Value Coding

Key-value coding is done with `-valueForKey:` et al. Since this is implemented in `NSObject` nearly all objects having properties (have properties accessible by key) response to this. Basically this methods forms a selector from the key and sends it to the object. Beside this you have the ability to build key path and there are some special keys, i. e. count.

This is completely implemented outside the compiler.

Instances of `NSDictionary` supports this.

B. Subscripting

`[]` is the syntax for subscripting. If the key between `[` and `]` is an object, it is keyed subscripting. The compiler transforms that syntax into a `-objectForKeyedSubscript:` et al. message. The receiver has to implement the methods.

Instances of `NSDictionary` supports this by simply sending `-objectForKey:` et al. to `self`. But there is a little difference, see below.

C. `NSDictionary`

Additionally `NSDictionary` implements `-objectForKey:`.

There is no right or wrong. Personally I would prefer the most specific message for instances of `NSDictionary`, `-objectForKey:` et al. However, keyed subscription might be better readable.

Key-value coding is good, if you do not know the type of the receiver.

BTW: Key-value coding and keyed subscripting let's you set nil values in an instance of `NSMutableDictionary`, while `-setObject:forKey:` et al. forbids that.

Answer (score 3):

`NSDictionary` provides the method `objectForKey:` to access its contents. The difference to `valueForKey:` is explained in depth in this related question: [Difference between objectForKey and valueForKey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062183/difference-between-objectforkey-and-valueforkey).

The `[]` operator is a shortcut to `objectForKey:`. Whichever you use doesn't really matter, but the former one is easier to read (less code noise), instantly clear in its intention, and you don't have to think about whether it's `objectForKey:` or `valueForKey:`.

So personally, I much prefer `[]`.

Comment: The subscripting is sugar for `objectForKeyedSubscript:`, not `objectForKey:` directly. (Also, `@[]` is a literal `NSArray`, not a subscript: remove the `@`.)

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes, surely without the (copied) ´@´. Doesn't it ultimately call through to ´objectForKey:´? Or does the ´objectForKeyedSubscript:´ indirection have some side effects?

Comment: Correct, on `NSDictionary`, it just calls straight through to `objectForKey:`.

Comment: It has side effects for the setter in a mutable dictionary: `nil` is allowed. Even this is no explicit part of the Q, one should say that.

Comment: `dict[key] = value` actually translates to `setObject:forKeyedSubscript`, which has the behavior of calling `removeObjectForKey` if the value is `nil`.  That what gives you the ability to remove objects by assigning `nil` to a key.